# Deploy and run BPMN processes with the Micro Integrator

Tags: wso2, bpmn, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

The WSO2 documentation says that the functionality of the Enterprise Integrator is now included in the Micro Integrator and API Manager.

How do I deploy and run BPMN processes with the new system? I can't find any documentation on it and don't see where to add a BPMN process to the Integrator or where to work on HumanTasks.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need the BPS profile of the Enterprise Integrator. But the BPS server is on maintenance mode and new features or development is not made on this. Therefore the Micro Integrator does not contain the features of the BPS profile.

If you want to use the BPS profile you will need to continue to use the EI (6.6.0 is the latest EI server)

Comment: What about this section in the api manager docs: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/extending-api-manager/extending-workflows/configuring-workflows-for-tenants/  is the BPMN now supported in the latest version? note that i found nothing under the micro integrator documentation though